# MongoDB Find function progress indicator in C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am getting large collection from MongoDB using official C# driver. This can be very time consuming, and I need to indicate progress in my application.
I am thinking about doing something like getting Count() from MongoCollection.FindAll() function, setting batch size (this I can do), and then subscribing to event like OnBatchRead (this is what I can't do).

Any ideas on how could I solve it?

Comment: Instead of doing a single query to the database and extract your data, re-think about that again, in most cases you don't need a large amount of data to be presented to the user in other cases you can do aggretaes, calulate values to improve queries, anyway you can do sub queries and push a subset of the query to the client, then over each iteration you present the progress bar you mention to the client

Answer (score 0):

If you know the total count of all documents, and you keep progress as you iterate through each one of them, you know the progress. 1/100, 2/100, 3/100, etc... No need to deal with batch sizes.